# C++: Use std::allocate_shared with boost pool_allocator and release_memory()

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, pool

I'd like to create some shared pointers like this

```
typedef boost::pool_allocator<MyClass> PoolAlloc;
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p = std::allocate_shared<MyClass, PoolAlloc>(PoolAlloc());
```

As I am going to be doing this a bunch of times, memory gets taken from the pool.

As the program flow continues the smart pointers get deleted / go out of scope and the memory is returned to the pool.

However the pool memory is still allocated and every once in a while I'd like to cut back on that unused memory and give it back to the OS.

For this purpose boost has the `boost::singleton_pool::release_memory()` method. However `boost::singleton_pool` is templated on the size of the allocated objects, like this:

```
boost::singleton_pool<boost::pool_allocator_tag, sizeof(MyClass)>::
release_memory();
```

I am now unsure whether this call would have the desired effect (my guess is no), because allocate_shared does not actually allocate from the given pool but from a different pool (holding objects of an unknown type of size `sizeof(MyClass) + sizeof(Control_Block)`).

My question is how to properly `release_memory()` from a `boost::pool_allocator` used with `allocate_shared()`. Would using `boost::allocate_shared()` instead of `std::allocate_shared()` make a difference?

Comment: As far as I know its not possible for a conforming program to return memory to the OS (with the possible exception of mmap).

Comment: By "giving memory back to the OS" of course that is meant in the same sense as a call to free() would return memory to the OS.

Comment: You can return page-size aligned blocks of memory (multiples of 4096 bytes, aligned to a 4096 boundary) via madvise(). That's what things like glibc's malloc() does. But you need to make sure everything you return is unused; I don't know how you can do that with the boost pool API.